# FullPage.js Overflow: hidden doesn't work on my body

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

I have a problem with the plugin FullPage.js (http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). It works but the css "overflow: hidden;" on the body doesn't work. I search a solution since two days but I have not find it yet.
Could you help me ?

My website :
VeillaultAdrien.github.io

The code :
https://github.com/VeillaultAdrien/VeillaultAdrien.github.io.git

Comment: Hi, Do you want to apply overflow: hidden vertically or horizontally? In your css file, Overflow:hidden is applied horizontally. If this is not the case then elaborate your query.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure to understand. I didn't know that overflow: hidden have two orientation.
I want to make an overflow: hidden on my body to make disappear the white band on the top of my website. And when, I look the code on the web browser with "F12", I see the css overflow: hidden crossed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why is happening, but this will solve it for you:

```
h1{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: It’d weird that the `h1` `margin-top` is doing this. Did you try on  new  fresh install of FullPage.js ?